# How Do I Completely Remove All Github Credentials From Visual Studio Code On Windows?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I had Visual Studio Code installed with Git Bash on Windows. I followed a tutorial a while back, don't remember which one, and I was pushing and pulling repositories fine to my personal github account.

To satisfy my employer's request, I wanted to create a beginner's tutorial on how to create a Github account, create a repository, download and install VS Code, install git bash and commit/push something to the newly created github repository using the gitbash terminal on VS Code, and brand it with the employer's logo using a video editor.

Everything went great, I followed the instructions in

How to remove git account from local machine and add new account

to remove my credentials in VS Code/Github so I could push the code to the newly created github account for the purpose of creating the tutorial.

But when I try to push, I get this error:

```
myaccount@LAPTOP-4KKKPK MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/oop/exercise1 (main)$ git push --set-upstream origin main
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/guestaccount/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

In the new github account I did not set a SSH key. The SSH key was stored on Windows. So I am stuck here. I have been google searching on how to remove the SSH key from VS Code, but was not successful.

In short, could you please help me figure out the steps to:

Remove ALL github configurations from Windows and VS Code including the prompt to request from me credentials for a SSH key?
Thank you

Comment: I must do this often when we deploy projects. I recommend that you use virtual machines with new OS installations. That way you know for sure there are no remnants leftover from previous configurations. Using cloud VMs is another good option.